# Máquina Virtual não compartilha pasta

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vmware

**Problema:**

---

Uso `Virtual Box` e `MVWare` em ambos os programas não consigo compartilhar pasta, utilizando a opção interna deles `Pasta Compartilha`.

Observe as imagens para uma esclarecimento melhor sobre o problema:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Foto 1: `Pasta Compartilhada` do `Virtual Box`

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Foto 2: Local onde deveria aparecer o compartilhamento que fiz no
>   processo anterior.

---

**Dúvida:**

Por que não encontro a pasta que está compartilhada?

---

> **Observação:** O compartilhamento de rede não é trivial já que a `Virtual Box` e `VMWare` permitem um compartilhamento interno. Mostro
>   o diretório `/mnt/hfgs`, nele encontrei a pasta quando comecei a usar
>   a Máquina Virtual e hoje não encontro mais.

Comment: Acho que tem que instalar um utilitário no sistema operacional que está dentro da Máquina Virtual, para habilitar esta forma de integração do Sistema Operacional que está rodando dentro da Máquina Virtual, com outros recursos do Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solução no VirtualBOX:

---

Sobre GuestAdditions: [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Temos que fazer o seguinte:

> As Adições de Convidado VirtualBox para todos os sistemas operacionais
>   convidados suportados são fornecidos como um arquivo de imagem de CD
>   -ROM único que é chamado VBoxGuestAdditions.iso . Este arquivo de imagem está localizado no diretório de instalação do VirtualBox . Para
>   instalar os Adicionais para Convidado para uma determinada VM , você
>   montar este arquivo ISO em sua VM como um CD -ROM virtual e instalar a
>   partir de lá.
>
> **[Tradução Google Translate]**

---

**Montando unidade CD-ROM na máquina virtual**

Montar o `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` que está na pasta `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` (no meu computador) dentro da sua Máquina Virtual pasta ir nas configurações dela. Observe a imagem.

[image: Imagem 1: Montando unidade de CD-ROM com o VBoxGuestAdditions.iso.]
*Imagem 1: Montando unidade de CD-ROM com o `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`.*

---

**Iniciando instalação**

Inicie a máquina virtual e vá até a unidade CD-ROM que parece com o nome `VBoxGuestAdditions` chegando lá execute `autorun.sh` escolha opção "Executar em Terminal" observe a imagem do terminal em instalação.

**Observação:**  Quando a instalação for concluída reinicia a Máquina Virtual.

[image: Imagem 2: Depois que foi executado autorun.sh essa é a tela de instalação do mesmo.]
*Imagem 2: Depois que foi executado `autorun.sh` essa é a tela de instalação do mesmo.*

---

**Visualizando pasta compartilha**

Agora fica de sua preferência acessar sua pasta compartilha via terminal ou console.

Observe a imagem onde está a pasta compartilhada:

[image: Imagem 3: Nessa foto podemos ver a pasta que está compartilhada.]
Imagem 3: Nessa foto podemos ver a pasta que está compartilhada.

---

**Legenda de cores da imagem 3:**

- Vermelho - Pasta onde está os compartilhamento
- Verde - Pasta compartilhada em [sua VM > Configurações > Pasta
  Compartilhadas]
- Azul - CD-ROM que contém o `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`. [sua VM >
  Configurações > Armazenamento]

---

> **Observação:** Sempre acessei a pasta compartilha em `/mnt/hfgs`, porém
>   acabei encontrando ela agora em `/media` como segue a imagem. Esse processo resolveu meu problema, espero que ajude a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Para funcionar, 
Instale o Guest Additions

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Isto irá habilitar esta forma de integração do Sistema Operacional que está rodando dentro da Máquina Virtual, com o recurso do Virtual Box.

Outra forma é compartilhar a pasta normalmente no Sistema Operacional dentro da Máquina Virtual, e acessar ela através de um compartilhamento de rede, como se fossse um PC normal na rede, utilizando a sintaxe

```
\\NomeDoPC\PastaCompartilhada
```